# how to open power shell window from a batch file to a new window

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, monkey

I am writing a DOS batch script file. My script will be doing following:

1. make a directory with mkdir command
2. spawn a powershell command to a new window ( not the same command window)
3. I would like to open this power script in a new window
4. run shell monkey -p  com.android.browser in current window

test.bat

```
mkdir c:\test_log_file
powershell adb logcat >> "C:\Testdata.txt"              
shell monkey -p  com.android.browser
```

I have a problem spawning a powershell into a new window.  How would I open a power shell in a new command window.

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

```
mkdir c:\test_log_file
START "Powershell window" powershell adb logcat ^>^> "C:\Testdata.txt"              
shell monkey -p  com.android.browser
```

The carets (`^`) are required to escape their special meaning to the command processor. The quoted first parameter is the Window title of the new window. Can be `""` if you wish.

Comment: However, It does not run the "shell monkey -p  com.android.browser" command until I kill the Powershell Window. Do you have any idea why ?