# Unable to open a second command window from batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have following command to start after other which does not depend on each other. However, with following command, I only can start #1, #2. My command #3 does not start . 
I would like to know if i have make any mistake. I did not see the the third line executed.

1. // make a directory
2. // startd adb logcat
3. // shell adb monkey

"test.bat"

```
mkdir c:\test_log_file  
START "powershell Window" powershell adb logcat >> "C:\Testdata.txt"              
START "Powershell Window 2" shell adb monkey -p  com.android.browser
```

Comment: Typo in the "Powershell Window 2" `shell` -> `powershell`?

Comment: `start PowerShell` works here from `cmd` (and from PowerShell where `start` is an alias for `Start-Process`). 1. Correct (as noted by @denis.solonenko) the second `start` line; 2. run something in that command that will not complete immediately so you have a chance of diagnosing this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your earlier question ([how to open power shell window from a batch file to a new window](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15650036/1248365)), I'm assuming that "shell" is a command you have available to you, and not a typo. Two possibilities come to mind:

1. Is "shell" in the path? If not, you need to provide the full path to this command. (Probably not the answer, because if this were the issue you'd get a popup error message telling you that Windows can't find "shell".)
2. Although you've titled the window "Powershell Window 2" in your second START command, this command should actually open a cmd window, not a powershell window. Are you looking for a new powershell window, when you actually have a cmd window that's titled "Powershell Window 2"?

If you want to start a powershell window, the command should be:

```
START "Powershell Window 2" powershell -noexit shell adb monkey -p  com.android.browser
```

Comment: I have tried the suggestion that you have mention; however, the power shell window 2 will not open and execute until i have to close the first Powershell Window. Just for your information, my goal is to have the first powershell window and powershell shell #2 run simultaneously.